# Error uploading application to AppStore - error 19011

Tags: iphone, xcode4, submit

I'm trying to upload an updated iPhone version. I compile with the distribution provisional and get the error -  "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)".

I'm trying to make the same process for my previous version and it works fine. So I guess it's not the provisional. The bundle id I using in my new application is similar to the previous. I changed the projects structures and added features.

There is another issue which might be related: the application runs well on device but when I'm trying to create an archive I get an error of not find .h files though they are in the path.

I will appreciate if you can assist.

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 0):

Apple's App Store is experiencing downtime lately:

http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/13/itunes-connect-down-for-maintenance-for-most-of-july-13/

Comment: Thanks but I find problems in signing the application even before submitting it up.

Comment: The problem was that need to skip install flag